# winbind id mapping issue

Tags: active-directory, samba, sles

I have got SLES 15 sp 2 server integrated with Windows 2019 AD server.I could login with ad user id in the Linux systems.However uid/gid are not reflecting from the ad.We have set uid( for eg: uid- > 8000 ),gid,login shell and home directory for user at ad user/group attribute level. Here is the smb.conf file

```
# smb.conf is the main Samba configuration file. You find a full commented
# version at /usr/share/doc/packages/samba/examples/smb.conf.SUSE if the
# samba-doc package is installed.
[global]
  workgroup = abcde5
  usershare allow guests = YES
  idmap config * : backend = tdb
  idmap config * : range = 5000000-5999999
  idmap config  ABC : backend = ad
  idmap config  ABC : range = 1000-99999
  idmap config  ABC : schema_mode = rfc2307
  idmap config  ABC : unix_nss_info = yes
  kerberos method = secrets and keytab
  realm = ABC.DE5.CORP
  security = ADS
  template homedir = /home/%U
  template shell = /bin/bash
  winbind offline logon = yes
  winbind use default domain = yes
  winbind refresh tickets = yes
  log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
  log level = 1
  vfs objects = acl_xattr
  map acl inherit = yes
  store dos attributes = yes

de5pw04:/etc/samba # id de5group1u1
```

uid=5000000(de5group1u1) gid=5000000(domain users) groups=5000000(domain users),5000001(de5group1)
de5pwd04:/etc/samba #

```
de5pwd04:/etc/samba # wbinfo -V
Version 4.11.14-git.313.d4e302805e14.32.1-SUSE-oS15.0-x86_64
de5pwd04:/etc/samba #
```

Please let me know,how to get uid/gid set on the ad to Linux system for the user

Comment: Please refer to this documentation link for more details: - https://documentation.suse.com/sled/15-SP2/html/SLED-all/cha-samba.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your workgroup is 'ABCDE5' then your your 'idmap config ABC' lines are wrong, they should be 'idmap config ABCDE5'. This has led to your users & groups being put into the '*' domain.